# After manually navigating within Intellij Project Explorer the Scroll to Source no longer seems to work

Tags: intellij-idea

"Autoscroll from Source" has been enabled - which works well normally.  The particular scenario for this question is that I have navigated to a different module and file within the Project Explorer.  After having done that I can find no way to scroll to source anymore.

- Navigate | Select | Scroll to source has no effect
- Disabling and reenabling Autoscroll from Source has no effect.

Any suggestions on what other workaround/tweak to attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a corner case that happens infrequently. I have not seen it again since that time. So: no answer, but not really to worry too much about it.